# Log all mysql queries for particular ip using php-mysql

Tags: php, mysql, logging

How to enable logging of mysql queries for particular ip using `php-mysql` extension?

I've tried to set system variables, but nothing works:

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '<some ip>') {
    mysql_query('SET log_output = "FILE"');
    mysql_query('SET general_log_file = "/var/log/sql.log"');
    mysql_query('SET general_log = "ON"');
}
```

Project is rather old, so don't suggest to switch from `php-mysql`, or use some ORM/DBAL.

Comment: You need to use `SET GLOBAL general_log = ON` to turn it on, otherwise nothing happens (just like you experienced).

Comment: Check this link:- http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33654/mysql-logging-activity-from-specific-user-or-ip

Comment: @RaviHirani - are you sure you understood the question? It's not about logging from IP, it's about having MySQL enable general log which logs all the queries (this is independent from PHP). The IP check above is not related to the **actual** problem.

Comment: @RaviHirani, I've checked the link, I think it would record ips of mysql clients, not the ip of web user. Also general logging for all requests is too heavy for my project.

I thought that with `php-mysql ` I can enable general logging for session based on php condition, smth I've mentioned in answer.